# Hoe to fetch records which is closed in 1 day in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

***How i can get all record who's are closing in one day in mongodb. For example closing date 6th DEC. Can i check it with 5 DEC date in mongo query ***

```
var start=new Date();
var dat = new Date();
dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 7);
var end=dat;
var criteria = {
       EndDate: {
            $gte: start,
            $lte: end
       }
 }
```

***using this condition first i get all the records which are closed within a week from today date***

Comment: Can you show a sample documents and expected result?

Comment: hi i have solved it. Thanks for quick reply.